# Unable to apply where condition in foreach loop in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@model IEnumerable<WIMMPortalServer.BAL.DTO.GlobalCodeDTO>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (@item.GlobalCodeCategoryValue == "115")
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @*<h6 >PICTURE FORMAT:</h6>*@
            <h6>@item.GlobalCodeCategoryName</h6>
            <div class="checkboxs round">
                <div class="element">
                    <label id="lblcolor">
                    @*COLOR*@
                    @item.GlobalCodeName
                    <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                @*<div class="element dark">
                    <label id="lblbw">
                        COLOR + B/W
                        <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>*@
                @*<div class="element">
                    <label id="lblwhite">
                    BLACK & WHITE
                    <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I want to use where condition with foreach loop instead of if condition but unable to do that. Kindly help me with the solution as I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where in `Model` as

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(c=>c.GlobalCodeCategoryValue == "115"))
    {
       
            <div class="form-group">
                @*<h6 >PICTURE FORMAT:</h6>*@
                <h6>@item.GlobalCodeCategoryName</h6>
                <div class="checkboxs round">
                    <div class="element">
                        <label id="lblcolor">
                        @*COLOR*@
                        @item.GlobalCodeName
                        <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    @*<div class="element dark">
                        <label id="lblbw">
                            COLOR + B/W
                            <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>*@
                    @*<div class="element">
                        <label id="lblwhite">
                        BLACK & WHITE
                        <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        
    }
```